# GROUP BY Issue - Grouping per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
   Sum(Earning) AS Amount, 
   MONTH(DateCreated) AS Month 
FROM 
   TheTable 
WHERE 
   DateCreated 
BETWEEN 
   @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
GROUP BY **???**
```

I want to display Earning per month and it should not group the month if it appears next year again e.g.

**May**, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, **May**, June etc.

Meaning if the year differs it should continue the list without grouping e.g. May 2015 and May 2016 altogether.

Thank you

Comment: `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag based on preponderance of evidence.

Comment: You should group by Month and Earning..

Comment: You want to group by year and month but only output month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the year in the `select` and `group by`:

```
SELECT YEAR(DateCreated) as Year, MONTH(DateCreated) AS Month, 
       Sum(Earning) AS Amount
FROM TheTable 
WHERE DateCreated BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
GROUP BY YEAR(DateCreated), MONTH(DateCreated)
ORDER BY YEAR(DateCreated), MONTH(DateCreated);
```

Comment: Excellent. I need to wait 1 minute to accept your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use  function for group by  month()

```
SELECT 
 Sum(Earning) AS Amount, 
 MONTH(DateCreated) AS Month 
FROM 
  TheTable 
WHERE 
  DateCreated 
BETWEEN 
   @DateFrom AND @DateTo 
GROUP BY  MONTH(DateCreated)
```

Comment: No, you can't use alias in `group by`.